# Running a multithreaded C program via python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pthreads

I have a multi-threaded C program, which runs perfectly fine as a standalone program. It uses pthread_create and pthread_join to execute some some logic. Now, I am trying to execute this code from python using subprocess. However, when executing via subprocess, it seems subprocess returns as soon as the main thread exits, but I wish to wait for the entire code to finish executing. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It _can not possibly_ matter whether your program runs as a subprocess of Python, or a subprocess of shell. You have a bug in your program that causes it to exit prematurely, and running as Python subprocess somehow exposes that bug. You need to find and fix it.

Comment: The C program is not my code, but it does work without issues when I run it directly on the generated data. Will check the given code and see if there is an issue.

Comment: It is *typical* that a pthreads program terminates when the main thread exits.  Such a program needs to make special provisions to achieve other behavior, and few do so.  But if your program did do so, then that would almost certainly be insensitive to by what other program it is launched.

Comment: However, it might be that the main thread exits sooner or that there are thread scheduling differences depending the program's execution environment.  In particular, it might have different behavior if its standard streams are connected to a terminal (probable case when run from the shell) then when its standard streams are closed or connected to pipes (probable case when run as a Python subprocess).